# Как в Java обойти все директории на диске без рекурсии?

Tags: java

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти способ в Java обойти все директории на диске без рекурсии?
У меня как на зло без рекурсии ничего не выходит.

Comment: без рекурсии -- это самоцель? или у вас переполнение стека? о_О

по делу: используйте стек отложенных заданий, будет вам счастье.

Comment: если не использовать рекурсию явно, придется ее эмулировать. А можно просто запустить dir/ls/tree/find и распарсить вывод:)

Comment: @VladD, только не стек, а очередь, именно ее Вы и сделали в ответе (псевдокод).

Comment: @avp: ага :) забыл обновить комментарий. Со стеком получился бы DFS.

Comment: @KoVadim, про эмуляцию рекурсии без рекурсии - можно подробней?

Comment: в ответах ниже приводятся примеры.

Answer (score 6):

```
File rootDir = new File(root);
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Queue<File> fileTree = new PriorityQueue<>();

Collections.addAll(fileTree, rootDir.listFiles());

while (!fileTree.isEmpty())
{
    File currentFile = fileTree.remove();
    if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
        Collections.addAll(fileTree, currentFile.listFiles());
    } else {
        result.add(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Очень крутой алгоритм.

Answer (score 3):

1. Делаете список директорий. Изначально он пустой.
2. Берете в качестве текущего элемента начало списка.
3. Заполняете его директориями, лежащими в корне диска.
4. Пока не дошли до конца списка: получаете директории для текущего элемента, добавляете их в список сразу после текущего.

Таким образом, когда вы дойдете до конца - у вас будет список всех директорий. Причем отсортированный так, как если бы мы обходили дерево рекурсией:

```
C:\A
C:\A\A
C:\A\A\A
C:\A\A\B
c:\A\B
C:\B
c:\B\A
```

и.т.п.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться дальше.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так (псевдокод)

```
queue<string> taskList = new queue<string>();
taskList.add(startDir);
while (!taskList.empty())
{
    string dir = taskList.first();
    taskList.popFirst();
    for each dirEntry in dir
    {
        if entry is directory
            taskList.add(entry);
        else
            processFile(entry);
    }
}
```

А вообще, почитайте про обходы дерева, например, [BFS/DFS](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html).

Answer (score 3):

Код на скорую руку, но рабочий:

```
import java.io.File;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootDir = "d:\\";

        File root = new File(rootDir);
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        int i = 0;

        while(i<files.length) {
            File firstElement = files[i];
            File[] subFiles = null;

            if (firstElement.isDirectory()) {
                subFiles = firstElement.listFiles();
            }
            else {
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            File[] temp = new File[files.length + subFiles.length];
            for (int j = 0; j<=i; j++) 
                temp[j] = files[j];
            for (int k = 0; k<subFiles.length; k++)
                temp[i+1+k] = subFiles[k];
            for (int m = i+1; m<files.length; m++)
                temp[m+subFiles.length] = files[m];

            files = temp;
            i++;
        }

        for (File file : files)
            System.out.println(file.getPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с `Java 1.7`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class FileTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path pathSource = Paths.get("Введите сюда путь к какому-либо каталогу, содержащему другие каталоги и файлы");
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(pathSource, new MyFileVisitor());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class MyFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor {
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path,
                                     BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) {
        System.out.println("file name:" + path.getFileName());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path,
                                             BasicFileAttributes fileAttributes) {
        System.out.println("Directory name:" + path);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

[The Java™ Tutorials - Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Обход всех каталогов без стека и рекурсии.

1. Добавляем корень в пустой Массив
2. i=0 (начало Массива)
3. Если i-й элемент Массива каталог, то добавляем все его елементы в конец Массива
4. i=i+1
5. Если i < длины массива, то переход к пункту 3

Comment: да, именно я так я и сказал

Comment: да тут половина ответов bfs

Comment: @Nofate я ваш алгоритм не понял и порядок вывода по вашему описанию у него другой. Здесь массив заполняется по уровням, да BFS наверно, только текущий элемент не удаляется из списка за счёт перемещения на следующий.

    /
    /A
    /B
    /A/A
    /A/B
    /B/B

Comment: @sercxjo i=i+1 равноценно удалению без "физического" удаления правда

Comment: @rasmisha, согласен, просто можно немного сэкономить памяти и операций в зависимости от используемых методов хранения, если нужен список всех файлов и директорий, в противном случае можно удалять обработанные элементы. Можно ещё добавить удаление по условию, если мы делаем поиск.

Answer (score 1):

очень удобно такую задачу делать со стеком. изначально в стек ложится корневая папка. дальше алгоритм такой:

```
1) выталкиваем последний элемент
2) получаем для папки список подпапок, добавляем все в стек
3) если стек не пустой повторяем пункт 1
```

Comment: К сожалению я ещё не умею работать со стеком. Я только начинающий.
Но всё равно огромное спасибо. Теперь знаю где ещё рыть.

Answer (score 0):

попробую расписать свой код подробно
можно так для директорий

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#coding=utf-8

import os

#-----------------------------------------------------
# Формирует список поддиректорий  от текущей директории 
# на один уровень ниже
#-----------------------------------------------------
def getCurrDir(rootDir=''):
    currListDirs=[]; onlyDirsLst=[]

    currListDirs=os.listdir(rootDir)
    for i in range(0,len(currListDirs)):
        currListDirs[i]=(rootDir+'/'+currListDirs[i])
        if os.path.isdir(currListDirs[i])==True:
            if os.path.islink(currListDirs[i])==False:                 
                # добавляем только дирректорию (исключая ссылки)   
                onlyDirsLst.append(currListDirs[i])
    return onlyDirsLst


#---------------------------------------------
# Формирует список поддиректорий, начиная от текущей rootDir
# на всю глубину дерева дирректорий
#---------------------------------------------
def getLstAllDirs(rootDir=''):
    oldLst=[]; newLst=[]; currPosLst=0

    oldLst.append(rootDir)

    while True:
        try:
            newLst=getCurrDir(oldLst[currPosLst])
            for i in newLst: oldLst.append(i)
            currPosLst+=1
        except IndexError:
            return oldLst



или так для директорий и всех в них файлов


#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Возвращает кортеж, где первый список - файлы, второй - каталоги
# Для одного уровня ниже от rootDir
#--------------------------------------------------------------
def getCurrFileDir(rootDir=''):
    currListDirs=[]; onlyDirsLst=[]; onlyFilesLst=[]

    currListDirs=os.listdir(rootDir)
    for i in range(0,len(currListDirs)):
        currListDirs[i]=(rootDir+'/'+currListDirs[i])
        if os.path.isdir(currListDirs[i])==True:
            if os.path.islink(currListDirs[i])==False:
                onlyDirsLst.append(currListDirs[i])
        else:
            if os.path.isfile(currListDirs[i])==True:
                if os.path.islink(currListDirs[i])==False:
                    onlyFilesLst.append(currListDirs[i])

    return onlyFilesLst, onlyDirsLst

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Возвращает кортеж, где первый список - файлы, второй - каталоги
# Для всех уровней от rootDir;
# Если Lst=getLstAllFilesDirs(...), то кортеж Lst==([fa,fb,..],[da,db,..])
# Lst[0]==[fa,fb,..]  - список файлов;
#                       Lst[0][1] - второй файл в списке файлов.
# Lst[1]==[da,db,..]  - список каталогов;
#                       Lst[1][5] - шестой каталог в сп. каталогов.
#--------------------------------------------------------------
def getLstAllFilesDirs(rootDir=''):
    oldLst=([],[]); newLst=([],[]); currPosLst=0

    oldLst[1].append(rootDir)

    while True:
        try:
            newLst=getCurrFileDir(oldLst[1][currPosLst])
            for i in newLst[1]: oldLst[1].append(i)
            for i in newLst[0]: oldLst[0].append(i)
            currPosLst+=1
        except IndexError:
            return oldLst

-----------------------
проверяем:

cDir='/home'

print '=  Ждём. Обработка  ============================='
Lst=getLstAllFilesDirs(cDir)

print 'Список файлов:'
print '========================'
for i in range(len(Lst[0])): print '%4d: %s'%(i,Lst[0][i])
print '================================================='
print 'Список каталогов:'
print '========================'
for i in range(len(Lst[1])): print '%4d: %s'%(i,Lst[1][i])
print '=================================================\n'

print '   Каталоги  другой функцией (отсортированные)'
print '== Ждём. Обработка =============================='
Lst=getLstAllDirs(cDir)

Lst.sort()
for i in Lst: print i
```

Comment: каким образом код на питон ответит на вопрос по java?