# Учёт подкаталогов при обходе содержимого папки

Tags: java

Я на JAVA вообще 0. Поэтому сразу извинения если что-то не так описал)

Возникла необходимость модифицировать один кусок кода:

```
  private static Map<String, String> getClassPropertyAnnotations(PhpModule pm) {
    Map<String, String> annotations = new HashMap();
    String parentPath = pm.getSourceDirectory().getPath();
    String[] paths = CIPreferences.getCustomLibraryPaths(pm);

    for (String path : paths) {
      File directory = new File(path);

      if (!directory.isAbsolute()) {
        directory = new File(parentPath, path);
      }

      if ((directory.exists()) && (directory.isDirectory())) {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
          if (file.getName().endsWith(".php"))
          {


            String fileName = file.getName().replace(".php", "");
            String className = ucfirst(fileName);
            String propertyName = lcfirst(fileName);

            annotations.put(className, propertyName);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return annotations;
  }
```

Здесь нас интересует кусок работы с директориями.
Получается так: передаются директории, они циклом анализируются, и происходит необходимая манипуляция.

НО этот код не учитывает что в директории могут быть подкаталоги. Мне необходимо чтобы подкаталоги тоже учитывались (причем глубина подкаталогов разная может быть).

Надеюсь описал доступно, может кто поможет :)

Comment: Самый верный путь, это рекурсивно пройтись по всем каталогам. То есть: 1. Получить лист файлов 2. Начать перебор 3. Если это каталог, то см. пункт 1. Если до утра вопрос доживет без ответа, напишу решение)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, можно заменить нерекурсивный обходов файлов в папке:

```
for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
    ...
}
```

на [рекурсивный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006711/5812238), используя Java 8 метод [`Files::walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-):

```
Files.walk(directory.toPath())
     .map(Path::toFile)
     .filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith(".php"))
     .forEach(file -> {
        // тут код обработки файла
     });
```

---

Ну или вот [одно из не Java 8 решений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538317/227016):

```
List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
Queue<File> fileTree = new PriorityQueue<>();
Collections.addAll(fileTree, directory.listFiles());
while (!fileTree.isEmpty())
{
    File currentFile = fileTree.remove();
    if(currentFile.isDirectory()){
        Collections.addAll(fileTree, currentFile.listFiles());
    } else {
        allFiles.add(currentFile);
    }
}

for (File file : allFiles) {
    // тут код обработки файла
    // в том числе проверка на endsWith(".php")
}
```

Comment: а старым дедовским методом можно примерчик? Ибо как я понял java8 не поддерживается этим плагином, которым я занимаюсь :)

Comment: @Manitikyl, извините, но нельзя (я даже начал его писать, но мне очень не понравилось, что придётся завести новый метод, а в него надо будет передать callback, а для этого callback придётся новый класс создавать...). Так что можете смело снимать плюс и ждать до завтрашнего утра, когда Роман напишет)

Comment: А если сделать костыль в виде цикла FOR, который там ну 10 раз смотрел бы вглубь. Вроде как можно запилить. или это прям совсем хардкорно будет?

Comment: @Manitikyl, мне кажется, лучше так не делать. Если что, я обновил ответ.